# '' not in list error

Tags: python, sql, list, parsing, indexing

This may seem like a duplicate question, but bear with me. None of the other posts solve my problem.

I have a list of fields in a table to parse. Here's an example:

```
fields = ['username', 'password', 'salt']
```

Then I have another list with all the fields of the table:

```
pattern = ['uid', 'username', 'password', 'salt', 'loginkey', 'email']
```

And another list with the values:

```
values = ['1', 'example', 'eladhksefhskf', 'aeaed', 'awdlkahflhef', 'awd@awd.com']
```

What I do is this:

```
for x in field:
    index = pattern.index(x)
    string += values[index] + ':'
```

The above code works for some databases but not for others. With the others, it gives me this:

ValueError: 'password' is not in list (pattern)

When it so clearly is.

Help?

Comment: @latheef itzmeontv Sorry, edited.

Comment: here where is `database` operation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but a much nicer way of doing this would be to create a dict by zipping the two lists together:

```
values_dict = dict(zip(pattern, values))
```

Now you can do:

```
for field in fields:
    print values_dict[field]
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that "password" inside pattern list is "password" not " password" or "password "

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Elizion it is a possible answer since python my generate valueerror if keys are not matching. and if you notice "field" while it should be "fields"

Comment: In that case, I would advise rephrasing your answer so it does not appear to be a rudimentary question.

Comment: is that logic thread safe? Since it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't

Comment: It works consistently for some databases. And it consistently fails to work with others. But the main gist is, that 'x' is in the list, and it's telling me that it isn't.

Comment: Are you doing any kind of modifications to the list? because it looks that you are getting this list from the database. And if this list is being modified by other thread at the same time then it will cause this issue. To check for this issue add a log statement to print the list before doing the pattern.index